# PHP + SQL - Group By Parent ID

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **permissions** table:

```
| id | name      | Other stuff | parent_id

| 1  | name1     | ...         | 3
| 2  | name2     | ...         | 3
| 3  | groupName1| ...         | null
```

Inside the permissions table i have the permissions themsleves, which are the ones that do have parent_id, i also have the groups (parents) which do not have parent_id because they are the parents.
So let's say i want to organize the groups in 'li' tags and inside those i want to list all the permissions that belong to that group.

I need the SQL that shows all the group names, and foreach group show the permissions. I assume that requires a couple of 'joins', (i'm kinda of a noob in sql).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's the current result: [open this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpatE.png)

See where it says 'Ver' , 'Opção 3' and 'ADMIN' , they are aligned, i wish the same result to both colums above those ('listagem' and 'manutenções').

Here's my current code for reference:

```
 <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU  <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">

                        <?php
                        $campos =  DB::table('permissions as permission')
                            ->select('permission.name as Grupo' , 'p.id' , 'p.name', 'p.parent_id', 'p.url')
                            ->join('permissions as p','permission.id','=','p.parent_id')
                            ->orderBy('permission.name')
                            ->distinct()->get();

                        $nomeAntigo = null;
                        foreach($campos as $campo) {

                            $data = (array) $campo;
                            //SO METE AS PERMISSOES QUE O TIPO DE PERFIL PERMITE
                            if (Auth::user()->can($data['name'])){
                            if($nomeAntigo !== $data['Grupo']) {
                                $nomeAntigo = $data['Grupo'];
                                echo '<li class="col-sm-3">';
                                echo '<ul>';
                                echo ' <li class="dropdown-header"><b>'.$data['Grupo'].'</b></li>';
                                echo '</ul>';
                                echo '</li>';
                            }
                            echo '<li><a href="'.$data['url'].'">'.$data['name'].'</a></li>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>

                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: what did you tried and what did you archived?

Comment: so far i really didn't try anything, i would like a base to start

Comment: in your permissions table, nothing says anything about permissions so it's a bit hard to come up with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are different solutions.

1) use multiple querys (prepared statements would be perfect). First query returns the groups. For each group query again against the database to return the permissions for each group.

```
$prep = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM permissions WHERE parant_id=?");
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT name FROM permissions WHERE parent_id IS NULL") as $row) {
    $r = $prep->execute([$row['id']]);
    // loop through it and echo
}
```

2) I'm not sure what's the correct name for the following is in english. In German it's "Gruppenbruch". Translated into englisch it's something like "control break". (if anybody knows the correct name, please edit or leave a comment)

```
SELECT pg.name as groupName, p.id, p.name, p.parent_id FROM permissions as pg
INNER JOIN permissions as p ON pg.id = p.parent_id
ORDER BY pg.name, p.name
```

Here's a working sqlfiddle for the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8fda1/2

now you can do something like

```
$resultset = $pdo->query(QUERY_FROM_ABOVE); // pdo
$oldGroupName = null;
foreach($resultset as $record) {
    if($oldGroupName != $record['groupName']) {
        if($oldGroupName != null) echo "</ul>";
        echo "<h1>".htmlentities($record['groupName'])."</h1>";
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>".$record['name']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: if it's not working please reply again. If it worked don't forget to select an answer for this thread.

Comment: any chance u can help me again? i need to show all the permissions, but i only want to show one group, for example lets say <ul>groupname</ul>, <li> permissions </li>,  right now the code makes multiple 'ul' , i just want one @Joshua K

Comment: @PedroFaria99 I'm not sure what you're meaning. <ul>groupname</ul> is not valid html... sooooo... ? Please update your question with the resulting html output you're looking for, ok? Then reply to my answer again and I will have a look at it, deal? :)

Comment: Sure thing :) , i will edit the post with some pictures for better understanding

Comment: @PedroFaria99 please share the output that you want AS CODE. The view from the image can created with different methods. Add html code instead of an image. The php code as reference is ok, but pls share some more lines of this code. The output of the `<ul>`-tag is completly missing. The html structure generation should be visible / comprehensible for me / the helpers for this part of the view :)

Comment: done, let me know if u need translations for the non-english stuff

Comment: @PedroFaria99 I'm sorry. I don't know how to help you :/ Your posted code is already a valid solution as I can see. What's the problem with this code? Can you show me the resulting html code you GET and the html code you WISH to create?